# Photoshop : Change Stroke Color Quickly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke, fill

How to Change Stroke Color of a Shape Quickly?

Like we double click on shape, it open a pop up color picker window that change fill color in real time without hitting "OK Button"

Is there any similar functionality for shape's stroke as well, like Ctrl/ Shift + Double click pop up a window for selecting stroke color?

[image]

Or any plugin or script can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin or script.  This is for Photoshop CC 2107. Older versions may be different:

When you use one of the Shape tools, you can change the stroke or fill colour in the tool options along the top.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but.. Firstly this not "Quick" because to change fill color we just have to double click the shape, a pop up color picker arise that shows color change in real-time before hitting OK button but..............

**This is far complicated, first we have to select layer, then click on stroke color, then custom color, then popup picker arise, and surprisingly, even it does not show colors changes in real-time, have to hit OK button to see changes, in case color not match then we have to repeat this again**

Comment: You don't have to double click the shape, it only needs to be selected using the Direct Selection Tool (A). Then the fill and stroke options will show up on the tool bar. There is no OK button to hit to commit the change - the effect is immediate.

Comment: Yes you are partially right, if we are selecting any color from pallets or using eyedropper tool, but.... when we need custom color, there is no way to check it in real-time without hitting OK button

Comment: So, add your custom colour swatches to the palette first.  It would seem you are going out of your way to make this as difficult as possible.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a robust solution. If i am working on new project where there are no pre-decided colors, in fact creating theme via testing different colors on elements... then how is it possible to add colors to the swatches when colors not yet fixed. Swatches are created only after the theme colors are finalized.

Comment: It is the nature of pixel based editors to require some additional effort to change colors. Switch to a vector-based editor if you want quick and easy color editing.

Comment: @Graphico, you can use the Adobe Colour Themes extension to create custom colour themes, you can store these themes in your CC Libary. When you are ready to use them you can add those themes as swatches to your palette, where they can easily be selected with the eyedropper.  In the colour themes Library you can even right click a colour from your theme and click "Apply stroke colour".  Adobe has already created all the tools to make this kind of stuff easy.

Comment: See [Screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/elSC6)

Comment: @BillyKerr, I appreciate your help, I am familiar with this functionality, but I am talking about doing it in easiest possible way similar to "changing fill color" by just double clicking. Your way is even more complicated 1 - Selecting color from Adobe Theme, 2 - Add it to Library, 3 Apply Stroke.  I want to do it in one single step.

Comment: @Scott, yea but you know we cant do everything in Illustrator :|

Comment: @Graphico If your colours are "not yet fixed", then I think Adobe's Themes functionality is a better work flow than what you have been doing. It allows you to organise colours in themes. Then once you have your themes created, choosing a colour is only two clicks - right click colour in the theme, and click  "Apply stroke colour".  I'm sorry, but I think this is about as easy as it gets.

Comment: I do know that.. so there's a trade off.. taking a couple extra steps to alter stroke colors in Photoshop is the small price to you pay for other things you need Photoshop to do.